# sas change last value by group to first value

Tags: sas

I want to change data of the form

```
id   value
1     1
1     1 
1     2  
2     7
2     7
2     7 
2     5
.     .
.     .
.     .
```

to

```
id   value
1     1
1     1 
1     1  
2     7
2     7
2     7 
2     7
.     .
.     .
.     .
```

That is, the last value by group should be the first value by group. I have tried the following code

```
data want;
set have;
by id;
last.value=first.value;
run;
```

But that didn't work. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save `first.id` value in variable and `retain` it.

```
data want(drop=tValue);
   set have;
   by id;
   retain tValue;
   if first.id then tValue=value;
   if last.id then value=tValue;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `first.value` and `last.value`:

- Do not hold the actual value, they just tell you if an observation is the first or last in a BY-group
- Cannot be assigned - `last.value =` is not valid syntax

Secondly, `first.value` and `last.value` only get set if the `value` variable is stated in the `by` statement. You should use `first.id` and `last.id` instead.

What we need to do here is:

1. Check if we are looking at an observation that is the first in the BY-group based on `id`
2. Keep the value of the `value` variable until the last `id` value is reached
3. When we are looking at the last `id` value then set the value from step 1.

Alexey's answer covers the actual syntax required to do this. Here's what the `first.id`/`last.id` values look like. (You can always view them by adding `put _all_;` into your datastep):

```
id   value  first.id  last.id  tValue
1     1     1         0        1
1     1     0         0        1
1     2     0         1        1
2     7     1         0        7
2     7     0         0        7
2     7     0         0        7
2     5     0         1        7
.     .
.     .
.     .
```